# Set the relation id to the one with a minimum id from the related table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have the following problem. 
I had a set of posts stored in a database table. Each user is able to tag their posts with a tag which already exists in the database, or create a new tag.

I have the tables:

`post` table:

```
id  content
1   test1
```

`tags` table

```
id  name
1   tag1
2   tag1
3   tag2
4   tag2
```

`post_tags` table (very small subset, has about 20000 records in reality)

```
post_id tag_id
1       2
1       4
```

Now due to a bug which we didn't notice, the following issue occurred: whenever a user edited their post, the update created new tags and associated them with the post instead of re-using tags already in the tag table (we could have spotted the error earlier if `name` field in the tags table was set as unique but this was not the case, even though it is supposed to be unique).

Now, we fixed the issue that was causing this, and I intend to remove all the duplicate tags created but first I need to reassociate the posts to the first tag created with that name (the id is auto-incremented so lower number means older creation).

I have tried the following query:

```
UPDATE post_tags
SET tag_id=(
    SELECT min_id FROM (
        SELECT min(id) as min_id, name 
        FROM tags t 
        WHERE t.name=(
            SELECT name 
            FROM tags t2 
            WHERE t2.id=tag_id
        ) GROUP BY name
    ) as `inner`
);
```

However this is failing with the message `Unknown column 'tag_id' in 'where clause'` . Normally I'd expect the `tag_id` in the inner `WHERE` clause to refer to the `tag_id` before the update (in the same way that `UPDATE table SET value = value + 1` works) but in this case it doesn't seem to work.

My expected outcome was to make the `post_tags` table to look like the following:

```
post_id tag_id
1       1
1       3
```

This is (in practice) equivalent to the previous data because the `tag_id` fields refer to tags with the same name as before. We need to do this as a first step so we can then remove the duplicate tag names and set the name column as unique to prevent this from happening again.

Example SQL Fiddle of my schema : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ff0b8
(I can't add the update because of the error).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Hello @Strawberry thank you for your suggestion. I have tried to make the question clearer. Hopefully I've succeeded, but if not do let me know.

Comment: The data set provided above, and the data set provided in the fiddle differ. Therefore it's not clear what the desired result should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
UPDATE post_tags pt
JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
JOIN (
  SELECT name, min(id) AS min_id
  FROM tags
  GROUP BY name
  ) p ON t.name = p.name
SET pt.tag_id = p.min_id;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/693dde/1/0)